# "An unknown error occurred" when authenticating between GitHub Actions and AWS using OIDC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iam, github-actions

I was unable to successfully authenticate when attempting to create a GitHub Actions workflow that would authenticate with an AWS IAM Identity Provider (IdP) using Open ID Connect (OIDC), based on this blog: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/use-iam-roles-to-connect-github-actions-to-actions-in-aws/

In GitHub Actions the error appeared as:

```
Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity
```

In AWS CloudTrail the error appeared as:

```
    "errorCode": "AccessDenied",
    "errorMessage": "An unknown error occurred",
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by not removing the space after `repo:` in the IAM Identity Provider Trust relationships' trust policy line that I had copied from the blog

```
                    "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub": "repo: <aws-samples/EXAMPLEREPO>:ref:refs/heads/<ExampleBranch>",
```